# test returning pdf with swagger in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, swagger, rswag

I'm trying to test an endpoint that returns a pdf file.

My action looks like this:

```
    def pdf
     respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        @pdf = ApplicationController.render pdf: some_number,
                                template: "show",
                                layout: nil
        send_data(@pdf, :filename => "something.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", disposition: 'attachment')
      end
     end
   end
```

and my test code looks like this:

```
  path "/pdf" do
    get "return PDF" do
      produces 'application/pdf'

      response '200', 'PDF generated' do
        schema type: :file

        before do |example|
          sign_in @some_user
          submit_request(example.metadata)
        end

        it 'returns a 200 response' do |example|
          assert_response_matches_metadata(example.metadata)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

but I'm getting the error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

I'm using: `ruby 3.1.0`, `rails 7.0.0`, `rswag 2.8.0`, `openapi 3.0.1`

Can anyone help me with my issue? and what is the correct way to test returning pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I solved the issue by adding `.pdf` to the URL:

```
path "/pdf.pdf" do
   ...
end
```